# Failure to boot when restarting Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, bootloader, grub2, ubuntu-16.04

After much work, I managed to install Ubuntu (16.04) on my Dell XPS-15 laptop (9550) and set up a "semi-functional" dual boot with Windows 10 (which I clean-installed prior to installing Ubuntu).

If I use Ubuntu and keep using it only, the booting (grub) is not a problem. However, if I boot into Windows 10 and then *restart*, I get a black screen showing boot error "no bootable devices found". In this case, I'm forced to go to BIOS settings, doing nothing else than exiting, and on the restart that follows, Grub is loaded normally... after a cold sweat, at first.

Note that while using Windows, if I rather *shutdown* completely and then boot again, Grub is loaded without issues. So there is something about *restarting* which is different from *shutting down* and has to do with it.

BIOS settings:

- UEFI

  - No legacy
  - Enable UEFI Network Stack
- AHCI (no RAID)
- Secure Boot disabled

Windows 10 details:

- Intel Rapid Storage Technology uninstalled and generic AHCI drivers activated
- Quick boot disabled

Machine:

- Dell XPS-15 (9550)
- Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz × 8

Some have reported similar issues and added an explicit link to *grubx64.efi*
 in the BIOS, but this did not resolve my issue; in fact it may have made it worse (or maybe it's just coincidental) -- I had to reinstall Grub2 altogether (with Boot-Repair).

Does anyone have ideas for what could be the cause of this nonsense? And if so, what would be a plausible solution?

**Update**

After going through forum posts, I thought it worth a shot to reinstall Windows, this time using Legacy Boot. I deleted all partitions on the SSD, and installed it from scratch. It turns out the problem is still there. I can shutdown and startup without problems, but I cannot *restart* Windows.

So it seems all of this has nothing to do with Linux / dual boot at all, but is simply due to a clean install of Windows that is somehow not XPS 15 compliant (I did not run into this issue with the original Dell installation of Windows 10).

I tried various combinations of BIOS settings and reinstalling Windows altogether, to no avail.

I am now asking... What would the logical next step be? Downgrade my BIOS version? Buy a new SSD and try it out?

**Update 2**

It seems the problem has been fixed with the latest Windows update. Leaving open in case someone goes through something similar.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was solved when installing the Toshiba SSD firmware (version 103), available on the Dell website but not installed automatically.

I think the Windows update was needed too.